# Comparing a list of CSV values in Linq to match those from second list with any value in first list

Tags: c#, linq, csv

There is a method that retrieves a list of CSV values, and I want to retrieve a list of similar items from the collection where similar is defined as any item from the collection that has at least one of the values which is in the item being compared to.

EG

```
public class thing  {
  public int id {get;set;}
  public string csv {get;set;}
}


var things = new list<thing>();
things.Add( new thing {id=1, csv="1,2,3"};
things.Add( new thing {id=2, csv="3,5,11,17"};
things.Add( new thing {id=3, csv="2,4,6"};
things.Add( new thing {id=4, csv="11,12,13"};
things.Add( new thing {id=5, csv="1,2"};

var item = new thing {id = 6, csv="3,5,11"};
```

So I'd want to do a linq query that would return id 1,2 & 4

Like var q = things.Select(i => i.id).Where(w => w. ?????

Just can't get my head around the question.

(oh and exclude itself, so were 6 added to the list it wouldn't be included in the result)

Comment: Do you want to get the id's (1,2 and 4) from list<things>?

Comment: store the values in array like var arr = new int[3]{1,2,3} and var q = things.where(w=>!arr.Contains(w.Id))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds relatively easy:

```
var itemValues = new HashSet<string>(item.csv.Split(','));
var result = things
    .Where(t => t.id != item.id && t.csv.Split(',').Any(itemValues.Contains))
    .Select(t => t.id)
    .ToList();
```

First parse and create `HashSet`containing the values that we are interested in, which enables fast lookup. Then select the items from the list that have at least one value contained in the set using [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method.

Comment: that sounds perfect :) thank you - i'll give that a try

Comment: yes that worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help, the key was to break it into those two parts, great use for a hashset, thank you again, had a complete brain freeze with this very much appreciated